# Codeigniter app returns blank output in CLI

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line-interface

I'm setting up my cron job controller that will only run within the CLI, I've not started with anything built, just in the testing phase with CI's examples. However, when running it I get no output or anything else, just a new line, this is the command I ran:

```
root@serv$ php /var/www/ci/index.php tools message
root@serv
```

As you can see in the *second* line, I get no output, just a new line to run an command but I don't understand why and I cannot debug it. The code contains this:

```
<?php
class Tools extends CI_Controller {

    public function message($to = 'World')
    {
        echo "Hello {$to}!".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

In my configuration file, the `$config['uri_protocol']` is set to `AUTO` so this does not seem to be the problem.

How can I debug this? What are the options that I may need to deal with?

I also have `display_errors` on and `error_reporting` on to `E_ALL`.

Comment: Well, it works - I just tested it with a basic CI setup (no changes to config.php).

Comment: @stealthyninja No, CLI syntax for CodeIgniter is `php index.php controller method params`.

Comment: @Repox That's strange, but I have no idea what I need to be aware of for changes I may have made towards CI configuration, that affects the CLI application. I don't understand why it doesn't return any output?

Comment: Any log file output?  It seems odd that you wouldn't get *anything*...

Comment: @landons Nope, no type of errors being logged.

Comment: You might try to double check that your command line is working ok generally. Run "php -v" to make sure it's doing output.

Comment: @DanBowling My command line is working, the cron jobs that execute commands to run Codeigniter under the commands does not work.

Comment: give the full path of php. you may execute wrong php.

Comment: I did, both doesn't make any difference.

Comment: This may sound stupid, but check path permissions (make sure every folder above your webroot has execute permissions for your webbserver's user or group). Also, you can omit the closing PHP tag. Or at least make sure there's no space or tab or new line after it.

Comment: Hmm. I use the `www-data` (I'm using nginx) user to execute PHP scripts, surely root would be able to run the command line?

Comment: What version of codeigniter are you using? This is the latest https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/tree/2.1-stable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, it was a problem with a `redirect('domain.com'); exit;` I had on an autoloaded library, because it was matching against the domain in a database, that way CLI doesn't serve a domain when it detects, hence I included a `redirect('domain.com')` with an `exit` which is why I'm not seeing any output.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this while i was playing w/ cli for codeigniter. It took me a while to troubleshoot the issue and found out that I forgot to except my controller on my login model which runs a `redirect` function.

Comment: Saved me about 4 hours of cursing trying to understand why, I owe you

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly suggestion, but might as well give it a shot...  @lolwut, what if instead of using "echo", maybe you have to "return" the output?

Comment: Nope, that didn't help - still the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the answer in the [Codeigniter Wiki](http://web.archive.org/web/20120606182807/https://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category:Advanced::CronScript).

By calling to the cron.php with parameters `controller` and `function`, and then define `CRON_CI_INDEX` to the refer to the file path of your main `index.php`.

For example,

```
php /var/www/ci/cron.php --run=/tools/message
```

Comment: That didn't help too :( I still get no output generated, no logs too.

Answer (score 0):

I have an application following this guide: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category:Advanced::CronScript running (and producing output). CI was only 1.7.2 when I did so, but it might still hold

Answer (score 0):

(CodeIgniter 2.2.0)

Add a route in /application/config/routes.php

for...

```
<?php
class Cron extends CI_Controller
{    
    public function process_dumps()
    {
        echo "Processing dumps..." . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

add...

```
$route['cron/process_dumps'] = 'cron/process_dumps'
```

Without this line there was no output on the CLI!